# Making different li (parent and child) the same width

Tags: jquery, css, list, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a horizontal `ul` navigation bar. Each `li` item is a different width. I want to make it so in the drop down menu the drop down "children" `li` items become the same length/width as the "parent" `li` items. Was thinking of using jQuery so it would be something like this:

```
jQuery("ul#menu li").width(); = jQuery("ul#menu ul li").width();
```

That obviously doesn't work but it hopefully gives more of an idea of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help. If it can be done using only CSS even better.

Comment: Having a look at your markup as well would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken as to how jQuery's width works over an array of elements, the problem with Johlin's answer is that theres no way to know which LI's width would be used as the new width.
CSS would mean that the widths would be static and if you need to change the LI's content you will probably have to change the CSS too. If that's not an issue then CSS would definitely be the way to go.
Another jQuery Approach would be:

```
$('ul#nav li').each(function () {
    $(this).find('li').width($(this).outerWidth(true));
});
```

This would set all the children LI's widths to the parent width

Comment: Vmex151, this nearly works for me, problem is I think with the padding and everything the "width" attribute is a little off. Is there any way to do this using the jQuery .css('width') method? Thanks for your help.

Comment: hereandnow78 made an excellent point that this assumes that parent will always be larger than the child. also the .width() depending on your jQuery version will return slightly different values (including/excluding padding) using
$(this).find('li').width($(this).outerWidth(true));
will pull in the entire width including padding/border/margin.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery seems like a poor solution.

I'd add a class to each parent li.

```
<li class="home"><!--nest ul goes here--></li>
<li class="about"><!--nest ul goes here--></li>
<li class="products"><!--nest ul goes here--></li>
```

Then you can target each one and it's children specifically:

```
.home, .home ul li { width: 150px; }
.about, .about ul li { width: 220px; }
.products, .products ul li { width: 100px; }
```

Comment: Chris, your right this would be the best solution but in my case I'm making a website for a client and they'll probably be adding links after I'm gone so I'm looking for a more dynamic solution, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a problem if one of your nested items (dropdown children) is larger than your main-item! if thats the case your children should specify the size of your parent li!

or was that exactly what you where asking?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
jQuery("ul#menu li").width(jQuery("ul#menu ul li").width());
```

This should work!